# Upgrade H2 from sonarqube 4.5.1 to 5.1.1

Tags: sonarqube, upgrade, h2

Today I have installed Sonarqube 5.1.1. Not having a lot of data/projects I'm using the H2 db embedded in Sonarqube.
Following the steps in the [Upgrading page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading) of the Sonarqube documentation I have the process up and running but without any data.
Copying the \data\es folder from the old installation to the new one create a lot of `failed to add mapping` WARN on the log file and end with the process being stopped.

The old installation is in the folder `sonarqube-4.5.1` in the root of my `D` disk, the new installation is in the folder `sonarqube-5.1.1` on the same disk.

What I'm supposed to do to copy the current H2 data to the new installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H2 DB upgrade is not supported. As you can see at the bottom of each page of your running SonarQube instance, **H2 must be used only for testing purposes**.

Comment: Can the data be migrated from H2 to another DB?

Comment: This is not supported.